# Firebase rules not working with code

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am not able to make the security rules in Firebase database working although the simulator shows they are in place.

A simple example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items":{
      "$itemid":{
        ".read":true,
          ".write":"newData.child('id').isNumber()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For above rules when I try posting an item from simulator with text value in 'id' it gives proper error as expected.
For Url:  `/items/-sdsd123`
And for data: `{"id":"MAC1", "name":"Macbook Pro"}` 
It gives write denied error in simulator as 'id' is not number.

However after **publishing** the rules and trying from code or browser data editor it allows the id to be text value. Below works:

```
var key = db.ref("/items").push().key;
db.ref('/items/' + key).set({"id":"MAC1", "name":"Macbook Pro"});
```

I am missing something basic but not able to figure it out, kindly help.

Comment: I tried with your exact data and it did block me from adding it: http://imgur.com/a/c3f0d

Comment: My bad, I was using admin script by mistake. I had 2 scripts configured firebase and admin with nodejs. Will close this issue. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: No worries, glad to help!